# Akka HTTP Setting Custom Content-type Response Header

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I need to set `Content-Type = "application/vxml"`,

Tried following code but it doesnt work.

```
  val contentTypeHeader   = RawHeader("Content-Type", "application/vxml")
  val cacheControlHeader  = RawHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3600")
  val acceptRangesHeader  = RawHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
  val vxmlResponseHeaders = Seq(contentTypeHeader, cacheControlHeader, acceptRangesHeader)

  complete {
    actorResponseFuture map { response =>
      HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK,
                   headers = vxmlResponseHeaders,
                   entity = HttpEntity(handleResponse(response, uri.toString())))
      }
  }
```

But it throws the following error,

```
2020-04-24 14:24:00.722  WARN  [ccc-vxml-activities-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Explicitly set HTTP header 'Content-Type: application/vxml' is ignored, illegal RawHeader
```

Earlier i was using following code to set `Content-Type` to `text/xml(UTF-8)`, but i cant use this approach as `application/vxml` is not there in `ContentTypes`.

```
complete {
  actorResponseFuture map { response =>
    HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK,
                 entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/xml(UTF-8)`,
                                     handleResponse(response, uri.toString())))
  }
}
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: First line is missing
val contentTypeHeader   = RawHeader("Content-Type", "application/vxml")
  val cacheControlHeader  = RawHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3600")
  val acceptRangesHeader  = RawHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
  val vxmlResponseHeaders = Seq(contentTypeHeader, cacheControlHeader, acceptRangesHeader)

Comment: Isn't `application/xml` enough? It appears as if "application/vxml" isn't a valid Content-Type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Comment: Akka HTTP requires that `Content-Type` be set _not_ as a raw header. The right way to have a custom content type is by registering it explicitly. See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/http-model.html#registering-custom-media-types.